# Read mutliple parquet files to pandas with select columns where select columns exist

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

When running the below i hit an error due to some of the files missing the required columns

```py
li = []

for filename in parquet_filtered_list:
    df = pd.read_parquet(filename,
                         columns = list_key_cols_aggregates
                     )
    li.append(df)

df_raw_2021_to_2022 = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=False)
del li
```

How do i skip the file if it is missing the required columns.

Comment: `if "column1" in df.columns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are able to read a parquet file's schema and metadata with [`pyarrow.parquet.read_schema`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_schema.html) before loading it into a Dataframe:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df_raw_2021_to_2022 = pd.concat([pd.read_parquet(fname, columns=list_key_cols_aggregates)
                                 for fname in parquet_filtered_list
                                 if set(pq.read_schema(fname).names).issuperset(set(list_key_cols_aggregates))],
                                axis=0, ignore_index=False)
```

---

Column names list (of parquet file) is presented with **`schema.names`**.

Comment: Thank you, is that strict. Will it load any file where the column names exist or only those that exactly match. I'm getting  `ValueError: No objects to concatenate` where it required columns (8 of 106 possible) are present

Comment: @mappingdom, checks if parquet file's columns list contains another predefined/required list of columns. See the update

Comment: thanks, had just found `superset` option and run that, this is great

Comment: @mappingdom, you're welcome,  you can also use `set(pq.read_schema(fname).names) >= set(list_key_cols_aggregates)`